# Sync Framework - file sync across domains

Tags: c#, authentication, impersonation, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm trying to do a one-way directory synchronization across domains (with no trust).  Ideally I'd like to use an existing sync framework like Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1, but can't figure out how to set up the authentication correctly.  I think I'll need to use NTLM pass-through authentication (described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/102716)), but initial tests are not showing success.

The code I'm working off of looks similar to this (based off the MSDN sample):

```
SafeTokenHandle safeTokenHandle;
bool returnValue = LogonUser("xfrtest", ".", "password", 8, 2, out safeTokenHandle);
using (WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(safeTokenHandle.DangerousGetHandle()))
{
    using (WindowsImpersonationContext ctx = newId.Impersonate())
    {
        sourceProvider = new FileSyncProvider(
            sourceReplicaRootPath, filter, options);
        destinationProvider = new FileSyncProvider(
            destinationReplicaRootPath, filter, options);

                    SyncOrchestrator agent = new SyncOrchestrator();
        agent.LocalProvider = sourceProvider;
        agent.RemoteProvider = destinationProvider;
        agent.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.Upload; 

        sourceProvider.DetectChanges();
        destinationProvider.DetectChanges();

        var results = agent.Synchronize();
    }
}
```

I have the "xfrtest" account set up locally on both machines with the same password.  The logon works for the source system (which I'm also running the code on) but fails on the target.

So the questions are...first, is it possible to do this using Sync Framework?  If so, am I approaching it wrong with pass-through? If not, any suggestions for good alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, this code actually DOES work.  My issue was that my non-production domains I was testing in had trust, which causes Windows to not fall back to NTLM pass-through authentication.  When I set up domains with no trust or non-domain machines, this works.